# Converting date filed from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MON-YYYY

Tags: date, msbi

I have checked the web looking for a solution, but haven't been able to get the error resolved.

A couple of date fields in the source:

> EFFDT
>     END_DT
>     CREATE_DT
>     UPDATE_DT

Source data:

> EFFDT  - dd-mon-yyyy
>     END_DT - dd-mm-yyyy
>     CREATE_DT - 11-Mrz-2009 08:20:26 AM , 22/10/1999 17:03:09
>     UPDATE_DT - 12-Aug-2000 11:33:16 AM

Target populating (without any transformation, straight move):

> EFFDT  - yyyy-mm-dd
>     END_DT - yyyy-mm-dd
>     CREATE_DT - 2009-03-11 08:20:26.000 , 2000-11-12 10:19:46.000
>     UPDATE_DT - 2000-08-12 11:33:16.000

Do I need the exact replica of the source data in target?

I have tried using derived column to transform, but am not able to succeed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: correction to my previous comment - I need the exact replica of the source data in target

Comment: correction - I need the exact replica of the source data in target?

Comment: i have tried to use Derived column for the date columns i have used the below logic   SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,5)(EFFDT),1,5)     i have got the below error                                                                                       [Derived Column [37]] Error: The "Derived Column" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Derived Column.Inputs[Derived Column Input].Columns[EFFDT]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the